# How to some text files to the project and have them visible when the program is published?

Tags: c#, csv, deployment

I have two CSV files with the data needed to run my C# program.

I have added them to the project:
[image]

When I publish I see them in the publish directory on the FTP server.

[image]

But when I install the app they are not accessible anymore. Can it be done automatically?